# Swift: UIButton vs UIView

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, it appears as though similar behavior can be achieved from a `UIButton` and a `UIView`. To give functionality to a button, `addTarget` can be called, whereas `addGestureRecognizer` can be called for a `UIView`. When should one be used over another? In particular, when images are involved, is it better to use a `UIButton` paired with `setImage` or `UIImageView` paired with `my_image_view.image = UIImage(...)`?

Additionally, what does a `UIButton` offer that a `UIView` doesn't (and vice versa)? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice is up to you but `UIButton` is **made for** if you want a view to be touchable. Moreover, the `UIButton` class includes every visual effects needed on a button (on press for example). It also has some attribute as `selected` which can be useful for some uses.

To sum up, if the **primary goal** of your view is to be clickable, then you should use `UIButton`.

Answer (score 2):

If the thing you want is a thing you tap and UIButton can be made to work, use it.  That way the default accessibility is just correct (for vision impaired users).

If you need features of a UIImageView, but also want to be able to tap it, then use that and add a gesture.  You should also consider using the accessibility features to make it possible for vision impaired users to know that you intend the image to be tappable.